# Get InnerHTML from Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    <div class="quantity-selector">
    <span class="quantity-element decrease_qty">-</span>
    <span class="quantity-element quantity-digit">1</span>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity">
    <span class="quantity-element increase_qty">+</span>
    </div>
```

Trying to get the innerhtml from "quantity-element quantity-digit" class

Comment: Remember that `classes` are normally used to refer to multiple elements, so just bear that in mind.  You may wish to apportion your `<span>` with an id to enhance specificity.

Comment: Is there a way to select which DIV before selecting the CLass need to get the data from a class called "one_price" within a DIV called "Main"


I have tried the $('main').find('.one_price') but can not seem to get the value inside the class from this approach any ideas

Comment: if by "called" you mean the `name` attribute, you may enjoy luck with `$('div[name="main"]').find('div[name="one_price"]').html(...);`.  Alternatively if these are classes, use `$('div.main').find('div.one_price').html(...);` &c

Comment: There are mulitple classes called one-price so I need to get the data from the class inside a DIV (which the DIV ID = "Main" and the class = "one_price"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've tagged jQuery, try this:

```
var innerHtml = $('.quantity-element.quantity-digit').html(); // = 1
```

Comment: Is there a way to select which DIV before selecting the CLass need to get the data from a class called "one_price" within a DIV called "Main" I have tried the $('main').find('.one_price') but can not seem to get the value inside the class from this approach any ideas

Comment: @user3142655 Assuming `main` is an id, you would need to use `$('#main .one_price')` I would suggest you read the selectors section of http://api.jquery.com

Answer (score 5):

If you want a non-jQuery approach, this will work from IE8 and above (and of course in any other modern browser):

```
var html = document.querySelector(".quantity-element.quantity-digit").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<div class="quantity-selector">
    <span class="quantity-element decrease_qty">-</span>
    <span class="quantity-element quantity-digit">Hi user3142655</span>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity">
    <span class="quantity-element increase_qty">+</span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
console.log (document.getElementsByClassName("quantity-element quantity-digit")[0].innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// with querySelector in Javascript 
console.log(document.querySelector(".quantity-element.quantity-digit").innerHTML);

// with Jquery
console.log($('.quantity-element.quantity-digit').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity-selector">
    <span class="quantity-element decrease_qty">-</span>
    <span class="quantity-element quantity-digit">1</span>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity">
    <span class="quantity-element increase_qty">+</span>
</div>
```